# Python. How to take custom type objects from *args

Tags: python

I have the following method:

```
def _loginEventHandler(cmdID, *args):
    if cmdID == Login.LOGIN_LOGED:
        user = args[0]
        print("User",user.userTypeID,"logged in")
```

that method is called like this from a different module:

```
user = User(nUserSelected)    
_loginEventHandler(Login.LOGIN_LOGED,user)
```

the interpreter throws an AttributeError:

> file "/main.py", line 79, in _loginEventHandler
>       print("User",user.userTypeID,"logged in")
>   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'userTypeID'

The question is what is the proper way of taking arguments from *args (specially if they are custom types like with "User") and why is it taking a tuple from args[0]

Comment: Your print statement has a tuple. Maybe you want to remove the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include `self` in the definition of the method. The first argument passed to a method is always the instance itself. That means that in your method, `cmdID` is taking the value of the instance, and the first element of `args` is actually the value of `Login.LOGIN_LOGED`, which is presumably a tuple.

Comment: _loginEventHandler is aModule method, not a Class method, that's why there is no self attribute. I have edited the question to eliminate the "self" before the call to "_loginEventHandler", it was a mistake copied from the original code since it is a little bit complex and i'm trying to make the question simple and direct.

Comment: Well I suspect that your edits are hiding the problem. As it is, unless User is a function that returns a tuple, this code would not give the issue you state. Maybe you should try and print the value of `args` and/or `args[0]` within your function to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to come up with a minimal version of the User class and a Login Enum. But I don't see any problems here. The output seems okay

```
from enum import Enum

class Login(Enum):
    LOGIN_LOGED = 1

class User:
    def __init__(self, userTypeID):
        self.userTypeID = userTypeID


user = User(1)    
_loginEventHandler(Login.LOGIN_LOGED, user)
```

which gives

```
('User', 1, 'logged in')
```